# Java closure introduction

Tags: java, java-8

Can any one please describe this sort of code to understand Java closure.

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> l, final {T, T=>Number} block) {

    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T arg0, T arg1) {
            return block.invoke(arg0, arg1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java 7 doesn't have closures. Support for closures have been deferred to Java 8.

Comment: Technically inner classes are closures (they define functions with access to identifiers of an enclosing scope). What Java 7 doesn't have is *elegant* closures.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Important note:** The question was regarding an earlier *proposal*. This was not the syntax chosen. See this Q/A as a "historical reference".

---

This syntax is described in the [BGGA-proposal](http://javac.info/) by Gilad Bracha, Neal Gafter, James Gosling, and Peter von der Ahé.

This snippet of code can be described as follows:

1. It takes as the second argument a function taking parameters `(T, T)` and returning `Number` (and assigns it to parameter `block`)
2. It then creates a `Comparator<T>` out of it. This it does by implementing the `compare` method by delegating it to a call to `block`.
3. Passes this comparator to the `Collections.sort` method.

---

Here comes a break down of the syntax:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> l, final {T, T=>Number} block) {
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

An argument called `block` which is of type *"function that takes two `T` and returns a `Number`"*.

```
    Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T arg0, T arg1) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

An ordinary call to `Collections.sort` with an instance of an anonymous subclass of `Comparator` as second argument...

```
        ...
            return block.invoke(arg0, arg1);
        ...
```

...which returns the number computed by the function defined by the `block` argument.

---

Put in terms of classical Java, your snippet would correspond to something like

```
interface Block<T> {
    public int invoke(T arg1, T arg2);
}


class Test {
    public static <T> void sort(List<T> l, final Block<T> block) {
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<T>() {
            public int compare(T arg0, T arg1) {
                return block.invoke(arg0, arg1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant wait to have that in Java. Tired of dozes of fire...Event() methods in my observables.

Comment: For a good explanation of the latest state of the lambdas, have a look at http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/collections-overview.html

Answer (score 4):

As @axtavt points out, Java 7 is (unfortunately) not going to have closures.  However, Groovy does, runs on the JVM, and integrates very nicely with other Java code.  I'd [read](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) this for more information.